# How to hook wp_mail to add a custom email as BCC for each sent email?

Tags: functions, hooks, email

Is there a way to hook into the [wp_mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) function to add a custom email as hidden (BCC) copy to each email sent?

If so, how?

-edit-

It's not like I want to send an email with BCC, I would like to make the necessary hooks to add the BCC to every sent email (many different functions in my theme make use of `wp_mail`)

Comment: Please search the site before asking. Thank you. Also always show your research and what you've tried to prevent down votes closing it down either as duplicate or as "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @kaiser Its not the same question, he wants to add bbc to one custom email, I want to hook the function to add bbc to ANY sent email...

Comment: First: You already got a chance to fix your question. You didn't file an [edit]. Luckily it's not over yet: [edit] the question, clear out the difference (and show what you've tried) and cast a reopen vote. If it's a good question afterwards it will be reopened. Also: Search the site. There're dozens of questions that show you how to use the `phpmailer_init` and `wp_mail` filters. Combine that with the other question args and Bcc part and **actually try** something yourself and tell us where you failed.

Comment: _"I Dont think its an exact dupicate"_ ... please don't edit what you think differs your question from another one. Just write a good question that has everything explained on [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you talking about BCC (with two Cs), as in _Blind Carbon Copy_ - or do you want to make BBQ? SCNR. If the former is the case, did you see my answer below?

Comment: BBQ sounds great! Sorry, i misspelled (them all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options:

1. The function is pluggable (i.e., you could write up your own `wp_mail` function and make it do what you'd like).
2. There's the `phpmailer_init` hook, which gives you access to the `$phpmailer` object (and thus lets you `AddBcc` another email address.
3. There's the `wp_mail` hook, which gives you (amongst other things) access to `$headers`, where you could add another email address to the `'bcc'` field.

Comment: Thank you for you anser, I will investigate the options, as I'm not sure where to start yet!